# What am I doing wrong when trying to conditionally style in React?

Tags: reactjs

**I have updated this for changes**

I am trying to conditionally render a CSS class...

I currently have this in my stateless component:

```
<input className= {props.completed && "strike-through"} type="checkbox" onClick= {() => props.onDone(todo)} />
```

As you can see there, I have it set up (assuming it is correct) to  apply a CSS class based off the condition of `props.completed`, which represents a boolean assigned to `this.state.completed` in my state object.

I am trying to make this all happen by passing `props.onDone(todo)` up to my stateful component, when a checkbox is checked/unchecked. This is connected to the handler `handleComplete(todo)`, which I want to use to change the state of `this.state.completed` and thereby change the CSS style in the stateless component. So far I have this in it:

```
  handleComplete(todo) {
   var completedTodo = todo.id;
   var found =this.state.todos.find(todoBeforeComplete=>todoBeforeComplete.id === completedTodo);
     if(found) found.completed = !found.completed;
     this.setState({ 
     completed: found.completed,
     todos: [...this.state.todos]
  });
  }
```

I have been able to manage changing this completed status to T/F by doing this. But for some reason it is not changing the CSS class like I want it too...

Comment: Can you try setting the className to a string instead of boolean? i.e. className= {(props.completed && "strike-through") ? 'true' : 'false'} not sure if it'd help but I haven't seen situations where you set the class to a boolean

Answer (score 1):

Your input tag should work, but you better do what [react recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) - pass a plain string or use `ckassnames` library - it's very convenient.

Now about the state: 
would be much better to have todos as objects (id is a key), e.g:

```
state = {
  ...
  todos: {
    1: { 
       id: 1,
       name: 'todo1',
       completed: true,
    },
    2: { 
       id: 2,
       name: 'todo2',
       completed: false,
    }
  }
}
```

What should you do in your `toggleComplete` then:

```
toggleComplete(todoId) {
  this.setState(({ todos }) => ({ 
    todos: { 
      ...todos,
      todoId: {
        ...todos.todoId,
        completed: !state.todos.todoId.completed
      }
    }
  }))
}
```

then to map through your todos object in a render you can use

```
Object.keys(this.state.todos).map()
// or
_.values(this.state.todos).map()  // [https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#values][2]
// or 
_.map(this.state.todos, todo => {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the classname with 'template literals' instead of strings while using conditions under JSX, like this:

```
<input className= {`${props.completed ? "strike-through" : ""}`} type="checkbox" onClick= {() => props.onDone(todo)} />
```

Also, it's recommended to use a ternary operator returning an empty string when your condition isn't met; otherwise, you might end up seeing a classname="false" in your html code later on.